# Como logro repetir condicionales en else final?

Tags: python

```
curso = int(input("Seleccione un curso según su número: "))
if curso == 1:
    k = lista_cursos[0]
    crear_parcial()
elif curso == 2:
    k = lista_cursos[1]
    crear_parcial()
elif curso == 3:
    k = lista_cursos[2]
    crear_parcial()
elif curso == 4:
    k = lista_cursos[3]
    crear_parcial()
elif curso == 5:
    k = lista_cursos[4]
    crear_parcial()
else:
    while curso < 1 or curso > 5:
        print("Opción invalida, por favor ingrese un curso valido")
        curso = int(input("Seleccione un curso: "))     
    crear_parcial()
```

Como logro repetir todos los condicionales puestos arriba en el else final? Simplemente quiero que se repita todo lo anterior en caso de que el usuario ingrese una opcion incorrecta?

Comment: No necesitas el `else`, encierra todos tus `if`, `elif` en el `while`

Comment: No necesitas todos esos condicionales, basta con `k = lista_cursos[curso - 1]` y solo un `if curso in range(1,6): break`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Christian, realmente era algo desconocido para mí ya que apenas inicio en python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al solicitar datos al usuario por teclado, se debería gestionar los posibles errores, si el usuario introduce unaa letra el programa rompería.

Para evitarlo  puedes envolverlo en un `try/except`.

Tambien tienes `raise` que genera un error si el número no está en el rango buscado.

**Con gestión de errores:**

```
def crea_parcial(num_curso):
    print(f'Funciona, es el curso {num_curso}')


while True:
    try:
        curso = int(input("Seleccione un curso según su número: "))
        #   if curso < 1 or curso > 5:
        #   if not 1 <= curso <= 5:
        if curso not in range(1, 6):
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('No es un número de curso válido')

crea_parcial(curso)
```

Observa que en el `if` te hago 3 propuestas para validar que esté en el rango de `cursos`

**Sin gestión de errores**

Si no deseas gestionar errores porque aun no llegaste en tu curso a ello la opción podría ser:

```
while True:
    curso = int(input("Seleccione un curso según su número: "))
    if curso in range(1, 6):
        break

crea_parcial(curso)
```

Comment: Yo trataria de limitar el except unicamente al valueerror y poner dentro del try el menor código posible. Asi se reducen las posibilidades de que se capture una excepcion no deseada.

Comment: @DanteS. `except ValueError:` lo tengo claro pero, te parece válido validar si el número está en el rango y generar un error con `raise ValueError` ?

Comment: No digo que no sea valido. Sobre tu duda, creo que no hay ningún problema con ello.

Comment: Modifico la gestión de errores. Gracias @DanteS.

Comment: De nada Tomy c:

Answer (score 0):

creo que podria ser mucho mas facil hacer algo asi:

```
if(curso > 1 and curso < 5):
 k = lista_cursos[curso - 1]
 crear_parcial()
else:
 //hacer que el usuario vuelva a ingresar el numero
```

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la diferencia de esta respuesta con el comentario de Christian?

Comment: Lei rapido su repuesta, luego de publicar la mia la lei mejor y era basicamente lo mismo, creo que simplemente "codifique" mas lo que él dijo